# Set environment inside `nsenter /bin/bash`

Tags: environment-variables, namespace, util-linux

I'm entering a namespace with `nsenter -m -u -i -n -p -t $PID /bin/bash`. However, `printenv` inside this namespace doesn't have everything I need. I'd like to send these variables in, but I'd like to avoid prefixing my bash command like `KEY=VALUE KEY2=VALUE2 /bin/bash`.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Are the variables already set? You can pass environment around with `$(set)`.

Comment: @mikeserv they're not already set unfortunately. Also, since this is an isolated namespace, I don't actually want to inherit my user's environment. I'm just looking for a more convenient way to establish the environment when entering the namespace.

Comment: I understand how they work - I just asked my own question on them the other day. It seems to me though they're more useful the other way round - I wouldn't mind their inheritance of my environment, just they're later affecting it. You could of course use something like this: `nsenter ... 5<<IN\nparam=val ; ${param=$name}=val...\nIN\n ;` and the fd would be available to you in the namespace. So you could `set -- $(cat <&5)` or even `. /dev/fd/5` at any time. You could use the shell's `.dot` with any file as well.

Comment: And for that matter: `nsenter ... ENV=./env_script sh -i`

Comment: @mikeserv can you elaborate in an answer? That last bit with `ENV` seems on track but I don't fully understand

Comment: Is this environmental variables that you want to inherit from the calling shell? Perhaps this is more to do with `sudo` than `nsenter` (if that is what you are using). Maybe you want to use `sudo -E` or set up `env_keep` in `/etc/sudoers`.

Comment: I don't understand: why not `nsenter … env -i VAR1=VALUE1 … bash`?

Comment: @Gilles that would work, but I was hoping for a more succinct way. Perhaps by leveraging an rc type file. It gets a bit out of hand when there's a bunch of variables.

Comment: I think I've got it. I was just answering your other question actually... But it doesnt have to get out of hand - just use a positional parameter array or a function. Or a heredoc with defaults that you define occasionally as you needed declaratives like `fn() ( nsenter ... )  5<<DEFS\n${param=thing}\nDEFS\nparam=nothing fn`

Answer (score 1):

I can't do much more right now, but it looks like you can use switches like `--rc-file`, or `--profile,` etc.

```
man bash
```

...

> If  bash  is  invoked with the name sh, it tries to mimic the startup
>   behavior of
>          historical versions of sh as closely as possible, while conforming to  the  POSIX
>          standard  as well.  When invoked as an interactive login shell, or a non-interac‐
>          tive shell with the --login option, it first attempts to read  and  execute  com‐
>          mands  from  /etc/profile  and ~/.profile, in that order.  The --noprofile option
>          may be used to inhibit this behavior.  When invoked as an interactive shell  with
>          the name sh, bash looks for the variable ENV, expands its value if it is defined,
>          and uses the expanded value as the name of a file to read and execute.   Since  a
>          shell  invoked as sh does not attempt to read and execute commands from any other
>          startup files, the --rcfile  option  has  no  effect.   A  non-interactive  shell
>          invoked  with the name sh does not attempt to read any other startup files.  When
>          invoked as sh, bash enters posix mode after the startup files are read.
>
> When bash is started in posix mode, as with the --posix command line  option,  it
>          follows  the  POSIX standard for startup files.  In this mode, interactive shells
>          expand the ENV variable and commands are read and executed from  the  file  whose
>          name is the expanded value.  No other startup files are read.