# How do I source another process's environment variables?

Tags: shell, environment-variables, proc

If I examine `/proc/1/environ` I can see a null-byte-delimited string of process `1`'s environment variables. I'd like to bring these variables into my current environment. Is there an easy way to do this?

The `proc` man page gives me a snippet which helps be print out each environment variable on a line-by-line basis `(cat /proc/1/environ; echo) | tr '\000' '\n'`. This helps me verify the contents are correct, but what I really need to do is source these variables into my current bash session.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 31):

The following will convert each environment variable into an `export` statement, properly quoted for reading into a shell (because `LS_COLORS`, for example, is likely to have semicolons in it), then sources it.

[The `printf` in `/usr/bin`, unfortunately, generally doesn't support `%q`, so we need to call the one built into `bash`.]

```
. <(xargs -0 bash -c 'printf "export %q\n" "$@"' -- < /proc/nnn/environ)
```

Comment: I suggest `. <(xargs -0 bash -c 'printf "export %q\n" "$@"' -- < /proc/nnn/environ)`, which will handle variables with quotes in them properly as well.

Comment: @JohnKugelman Thanks very much for the improvement, using `"$@"` instead of `'{}'`. For those wondering about the `--` argument in his improved answer: positional arguments to `bash -c command_string` are assigned starting at `$0`, while `"$@"` expands to include arguments starting at `$1`. The argument `--` gets assigned to `$0`.

Comment: Caveat: `/proc/"${SOME_PID}/environ` shows the environment variables of the process with PID `$SOME_PID` **at the moment that process was started**. Changes to that process' environment variables (including additions, removals, and modifications) are not reflected in  `/proc/"${SOME_PID}/environ`.

Answer (score 12):

In `bash` you can do the following. This will work for all possible contents of the variables and avoids `eval`:

```
while IFS= read -rd '' var; do declare +x "$var"; done </proc/$PID/environ
```

This will declare the read variables as shell variables in the running shell. To export the variables into the running shell environment instead:

```
while IFS= read -rd '' var; do export "$var"; done </proc/$PID/environ
```

Comment: Caveat: `/proc/"${SOME_PID}/environ` shows the environment variables of the process with PID `$SOME_PID` **at the moment that process was started**. Changes to that process' environment variables (including additions, removals, and modifications) are not reflected in  `/proc/"${SOME_PID}/environ`.

Answer (score 11):

In this answer, I assume a system where `/proc/$pid/environ` returns the environment of the process with the specified PID, with null bytes between variable definitions. ([So Linux, Cygwin or Solaris (?)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/123602/portability-of-file-descriptor-links/123659#123659)).

#### Zsh

```
export "${(@ps:\000:)$(</proc/$pid/environ)}"
```

(Pretty simple as zsh goes: an [input redirection with no command](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Redirection.html#Redirections-with-no-command) `<FILE` is equivalent to `cat FILE`. The output of the command substitution undergoes parameter expansion with the [flags](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion-Flags) `ps:\000:` meaning “split on null bytes”, and `@` meaning “if the whole thing is in double quotes then treat each array element as a separate field” (generalizing `"$@"`).)

#### Bash, mksh

```
while IFS= read -r -d "" PWD; do export "$PWD"; done </proc/$pid/environ
PWD=$(pwd)
```

(In these shells, an empty delimiter passed to `read` results in null bytes being separators. I use `PWD` as a temporary variable name to avoid clobbering another variable that might end up being imported. While you could technically import `PWD` as well, it would only stay put until the next `cd`.)

#### POSIX

POSIX portability isn't that interesting for this question, because it only applies to systems that have `/proc/PID/environ`. So the question is what Solaris sed supports — or whether Solaris has `/proc/PID/environ`, it didn't use to but I'm way behind the curve on Solaris features so it might nowadays. On Linux, GNU utilities and BusyBox are both null-safe, but with caveates.

If we do insist on POSIX portability, none of the POSIX text utilities are required to handle null bytes, so this is difficult. Here's a solution that assumes that awk supports a null byte as the record delimiter (nawk and gawk do, as does BusyBox awk, but mawk doesn't).

```
eval $(</proc/$pid/environ awk -v RS='\0' '{gsub("\047", "\047\\\047\047"); print "export \047" $0 "\047"}')
```

BusyBox awk (which is the version commonly found on embedded Linux systems) does support null bytes but not setting `RS` to `"\0"` in a `BEGIN` block and not the command line syntax above; however it does support `-v 'RS="\0"'`. I haven't investigated why, this looks like a bug in my version (Debian wheezy).

(Wrap all <s>lines</s> null-separated records in single quotes `"\047"`, after escaping the single quotes inside values.)

#### Caveats

Beware that any of these might attempt to set read-only variables (if your shell has read-only variables).

Comment: I did finally come back to this. I figured out a foolproof means of doing this or any null handling in all the shells i know about pretty simply. See my new answer.

Comment: Caveat: `/proc/"${SOME_PID}/environ` shows the environment variables of the process with PID `$SOME_PID` **at the moment that process was started**. Changes to that process' environment variables (including additions, removals, and modifications) are not reflected in  `/proc/"${SOME_PID}/environ`.

Comment: @Abdull Not quite. `/proc/$pid/environ` does show the process's current environment. However, the environment is in a fixed area of the process which can't be conveniently modified (in particular because the area is fixed-size). So any program that offers a way to modify its environment variables, including shells, is modifying a _copy_ of its environment which can't be seen from the outside (except by using a debugger).

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil', quoting [`man 5 proc`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html): "*`/proc/pid/environ`: This file contains the **initial environment** that was set when the currently executing program was started via `execve(2)`. [...] If, after an `execve(2)`, the process modifies its environment (e.g., by calling functions such as `putenv(3)` or modifying the `environ(7)` variable directly), **this file will not reflect those changes**.*"

Comment: @Abdull `putenv` modifies a copy of the environment. That's why it's not reflected in `/proc/$pid/environ`.

Answer (score 6):

I went round and round with this. I was frustrated with the portability of null bytes. It didn't sit well with me that there was no reliable way to handle them in a shell. So I kept looking. The truth is I found several ways to do this, only a couple of which are noted in my other answer. But the results were at least two shell functions that work like this:

```
_pidenv ${psrc=$$} ; _zedlmt <$near_any_type_of_file
```

First I'll talk about the `\0` delimiting. It actually is pretty easy to do. Here's the function:

```
_zedlmt() { od -t x1 -w1 -v  | sed -n '
    /.* \(..\)$/s//\1/
    /00/!{H;b};s///
    x;s/\n/\\x/gp;x;h'
}
```

Basically `od` takes `stdin` and writes to its `stdout` each byte it receives in hexadecimal one per line.

```
printf 'This\0is\0a\0lot\0\of\0\nulls.' |
    od -t x1 -w1 -v
    #output
0000000 54
0000001 68
0000002 69
0000003 73
0000004 00
0000005 69
0000006 73
    #and so on
```

I bet you can guess which is the `\0null`, right? Written out like that it's easy to handle with *any* `sed`. `sed` just saves the last two chars in each line until it encounters a null at which point it replaces the intermediate newlines with `printf` friendly format code and prints the string. The result is a `\0null` delimited array of hex byte strings. Look:

```
printf %b\\n $(printf 'Fewer\0nulls\0here\0.' |
    _zedlmt | tee /dev/stderr)
    #output
\x46\x65\x77\x65\x72
\x6e\x75\x6c\x6c\x73
\x68\x65\x72\x65
\x2e
Fewer
nulls
here
.
```

I piped the above to `tee` so you could see both the output of the command susbstitution and the result of `printf`'s processing. I hope you'll notice that the subshell actually isn't quoted either but `printf` still split only at the `\0null` delimiter. Look:

```
printf %b\\n $(printf \
        "Fe\n\"w\"er\0'nu\t'll\\'s\0h    ere\0." |
_zedlmt | tee /dev/stderr)
    #output
\x46\x65\x0a\x22\x77\x22\x65\x72
\x27\x6e\x75\x09\x27\x6c\x6c\x27\x73
\x68\x20\x20\x20\x20\x65\x72\x65
\x2e
Fe
"w"er
'nu     'll's
h    ere
.
```

No quotes on that expansion either - it doesn't matter if you quote it or not. This is because the bite values come through unseparated except for the one `\n`ewline generated for each time `sed` prints a string. Word-splitting doesn't apply. And that's what makes this possible:

```
_pidenv() { ps -p $1 >/dev/null 2>&1 &&
        [ -z "${1#"$psrc"}" ] && . /dev/fd/3 ||
        cat <&3 ; unset psrc pcat
} 3<<STATE
        $( [ -z "${1#${pcat=$psrc}}" ] &&
        pcat='$(printf %%b "%s")' || pcat="%b"
        xeq="$(printf '\\x%x' "'=")"
        for x in $( _zedlmt </proc/$1/environ ) ; do
        printf "%b=$pcat\n" "${x%%"$xeq"*}" "${x#*"$xeq"}"
        done)
#END
STATE
```

The above function uses `_zedlmt` to either `${pcat}` a prepared stream of byte code for environment sourcing of any process that can be found in `/proc`, or to directly `.dot` `${psrc}` the same in the current shell, or without a parameter, to display a processed output of same to the terminal like `set` or `printenv` will. All you need is a `$pid` - *any* readable `/proc/$pid/environ` file will do.

You use it like this:

```
#output like printenv for any running process
_pidenv $pid 

#save human friendly env file
_pidenv $pid >/preparsed/env/file 

#save unparsed file for sourcing at any time
_pidenv ${pcat=$pid} >/sourcable/env.save 

#.dot source any pid's $env from any file stream    
_pidenv ${pcat=$pid} | sh -c '. /dev/stdin'

#feed any pid's env in on a heredoc filedescriptor
su -c '. /dev/fd/4' 4<<ENV
    $( _pidenv ${pcat=$pid} )
ENV

#.dot sources any $pid's $env in the current shell
_pidenv ${psrc=$pid}
```

But what's the difference between *human friendly* and *sourcable*? Well, the difference there is what makes this answer different than every other here - including my other one. Every other answer depends on shell quoting in some way or another to handle all edge-cases. It simply doesn't work that well. Please believe me - *I've TRIED.* Look:

```
_pidenv ${pcat=$$}
    #output
LC_COLLATE=$(printf %b "\x43")
GREP_COLOR=$(printf %b "\x33\x37\x3b\x34\x35")
GREP_OPTIONS=$(printf %b "\x2d\x2d\x63\x6f\x6c\x6f\x72\x3d\x61\x75\x74\x6f")
LESS_TERMCAP_mb=$(printf %b "\x1b\x5b\x30\x31\x3b\x33\x31\x6d")
LESS_TERMCAP_md=$(printf %b "\x1b\x5b\x30\x31\x3b\x33\x31\x6d")
LESS_TERMCAP_me=$(printf %b "\x1b\x5b\x30\x6d")
LESS_TERMCAP_se=$(printf %b "\x1b\x5b\x30\x6d")
LESS_TERMCAP_so=$(printf %b "\x1b\x5b\x30\x30\x3b\x34\x37\x3b\x33\x30\x6d")
LESS_TERMCAP_ue=$(printf %b "\x1b\x5b\x30\x6d")
```

*NO* amount of funky characters or contained quoting can break this because the bytes for each value are not evaluated until the very instant the content is sourced. And we already know it worked as a value at least once - there is no parsing or quote protection necessary here because this is a byte-for-byte copy of the original value.

The function first evaluates the `$var` names and waits for checks to complete before `.dot` sourcing the here-doc fed it on file-descriptor 3. Before it sources it that's what it looks like. It's fool-proof. And POSIX portable. Well, at least the \0null handling is POSIX portable - the /process filesystem is obviously Linux specific. And that's why there are two functions.

Answer (score 3):

Using `source` and *process substitution*:

```
source <(sed -r -e 's/([^\x00]*)\x00/export \1\n/g' /proc/1/environ)
```

Shortly:

```
. <(sed -r -e 's/([^\x00]*)\x00/export \1\n/g' /proc/1/environ)
```

Using `eval` and *command substitution*:

```
eval `sed -r -e 's/([^\x00]*)\x00/export \1\n/g' /proc/1/environ`
```

The `sed` call can be replaced with an `awk` call:

```
awk -vRS='\x00' '{ print "export", $0 }' /proc/1/environ
```

But don't forget that it doesn't clear any environment variables that are not in pid 1.

Comment: Is the export redundant in @fr00tyl00p's answer? Cause if not it seems pretty important

Comment: Yes, the export is needed. I'll fix it up.

Comment: All of these commands choke on values that contain newlines and (depending on the command) other characters.

Comment: Correct. Will keep the answer for reference anyway.

Comment: Caveat: `/proc/"${SOME_PID}/environ` shows the environment variables of the process with PID `$SOME_PID` **at the moment that process was started**. Changes to that process' environment variables (including additions, removals, and modifications) are not reflected in  `/proc/"${SOME_PID}/environ`.

Answer (score 3):

It's worth noting that processes can have environment variables which are not valid Bash/Sh/*sh variables -- POSIX recommends but does not require that environment variables have names matching `^[a-zA-Z0-9_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*$`.

To generate a listing of variables that are shell compatible from another process's environment, in Bash:

```
function env_from_proc {
  local pid="$1" skipped=( )
  cat /proc/"$pid"/environ | while read -r -d "" record
  do
    if [[ $record =~ ^[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*= ]]
    then printf "export %q\n" "$record"
    else skipped+=( "$record" )
    fi
  done
  echo "Skipped non-shell-compatible vars: ${skipped[@]%%=*}" >&2
}
```

Similarly, to load them:

```
function env_from_proc {
  local pid="$1" skipped=( )
  while read -r -d "" record
  do
    if [[ $record =~ ^[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*= ]]
    then export "$(printf %q "$record")"
    else skipped+=( "$record" )
    fi
  done < /proc/"$pid"/environ
  echo "Skipped non-shell-compatible vars: ${skipped[@]%%=*}" >&2
}
```

This problem comes up only occasionally but when it does...

Comment: Caveat: `/proc/"${SOME_PID}/environ` shows the environment variables of the process with PID `$SOME_PID` **at the moment that process was started**. Changes to that process' environment variables (including additions, removals, and modifications) are not reflected in  `/proc/"${SOME_PID}/environ`.

Answer (score 1):

bash:

```
export $(cat /proc/${pid}/environ|xargs -0 echo)
```

Comment: Caveat: `/proc/"${SOME_PID}/environ` shows the environment variables of the process with PID `$SOME_PID` **at the moment that process was started**. Changes to that process' environment variables (including additions, removals, and modifications) are not reflected in  `/proc/"${SOME_PID}/environ`.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is POSIX portable:

```
. <<ENV /dev/stdin
    $(sed -n 'H;${x;s/\(^\|\x00\)\([^=]*.\)\([^\x00]*\)/\2\x27\3\x27\n/gp}' \
       /proc/$pid/environ)
ENV
```

But @Gilles makes a good point - `sed` will probably handle nulls, but maybe not. So there's this *(I Really think so this time)* actually POSIX portable method, too:

```
s=$$SED$$
sed 's/'\''/'$s'/;1s/^./'\''&/' </proc/"$$"/environ |
tr '\0' "'" |
sed 's/'\''/&\n&/g' |
sed '1d;$d;s/^\('\''\)\([^=]*.\)/\2\1/;s/'$s'/'\\\''/g'
```

Still, if you've got GNU `sed` you need only do:

```
sed -z 's/^[^=]*./&'\''/;s/$/'\''\n/' </proc/"$$"/environ

  #BOTH METHODS OUTPUT:
```

[image]

Well, POSIX portable that is except for the `/dev/...` which is not specified but you can pretty much expect that syntax to behave same on most Unices.

Now if this has anything to do with [your other question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/125100/set-environment-inside-nsenter-bin-bash), you might like to use it like this:

```
nsenter -m -u -i -n -p -t $PID /bin/bash 5<<ENV --rcfile=/dev/fd/5 
    $(sed -z 's/^[^=]*./&'\''/;s/$/'\''\n/' </proc/"$$"/environ)
ENV
```

The here-doc is extremely helpful in that it keeps the shell from screwing with any of the quoting we work so hard to handle in the subshell and also provides us a reliable path to a `.dot` sourceable *file* rather than, again, a subshell or a shell variable. Others here use the `<(process substitution)` bashism which works in much the same way - only it's definitely an anonymous `|pipe` whereas POSIX only specifies an `iohere` for here-docs and so it can be any type of file, though, in practice, it's usually a `temp` file. *(`dash,` on the other hand, does use anonymous `|pipes` for here-docs)*. The unfortunate thing about process substitution though, is it's also shell dependent - which might be an especially annoying issue if you're working with `init`.

This also works with `|pipes` of course, but then you lose the environment again in the end when the `|pipe's` state evaporates with its subshell. Then again, this works:

```
sed '...;a\exec <>/dev/tty' /proc/$pid/environ | sh -i
```

The `sed` statement itself works by holding every line in memory until it reaches the last, at which time it performs a global replace handling quoting and inserting newlines where appropriate by anchoring on the nulls. Fairly simple really.

In the `dash` picture you'll see I opted to eschew the \ mess and added the `GNU` specific `-r` option to `sed`. But that's just cause it was less to type. It works either way, as you can see in the `zsh` image.

Here's `zsh`:

[image]

And here's `dash` doing the vary same thing:

[image]

Even terminal escapes come through unscathed:

[image]

Comment: This is not POSIX-portable because sed is not required to handle null bytes. (That being said, POSIX portability isn't that interesting for this question, because it only applies to systems that have `/proc/PID/environ`. So the question is what Solaris sed supports — or whether Solaris has `/proc/PID/environ`, it didn't use to but I'm way behind the curve on Solaris features so it might nowadays.)

Comment: @Gilles No. But `sed` is required to handle ascii hexadecimal, of which the null byte is one. Besides, i actually just thought if a much easier way to do this still.

Comment: No, POSIX says that [“The input files shall be text files”](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/sed.html) (for sed and other text utilities) and [defines text files](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap03.html#tag_03_392) as “file that contains characters organized into one or more lines. The lines do not contain NUL characters (…)”. And by the way the `\xNN` syntax is not required in POSIX, not even the `\OOO` octal syntax (in C strings and in awk, yes, but not in sed regexps).

Comment: @Gilles you've got a point. I looked all over and I couldn't find what I thought I could before. So I did it differently. Editing now.

Comment: As far as I can tell, Solaris doesn't have `/proc/PID/environ` after all (it has several other Linux-like entries in `/proc/PID`, but not `environ`). So a portable solution doesn't need to go beyond Linux tools after all, meaning GNU sed or BusyBox sed. Both do support `\x00` in a regexp, so your code is as portable as needed (but not POSIX). It's overly complex though.

Comment: @Gilles - I was still editing. Which i do say in there, by the way.

Comment: Your first snippet (already present before the edit), using `\x00`, is fine for Linux, even if it isn't POSIX.

Comment: @Gilles Yeah, but sometimes thats not always the point to me. I do these things because i like to learn. I learned a great deal about `sed` doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution based on Gilles answer with few tweaks if you want to define ONLY missing variables that are not defined in your scope but are defined for process **$PID**

```bash
while IFS= read -rd '' var; do if [ ! -v "${var%%=*}" ]; then export "$var"; fi; done </proc/$PID/environ
```

Answer (score -2):

```
eval \`(cat /proc/1/environ; echo) | tr '\000' '\n'\`
```

Comment: This doesn't work if any value contains any shell special character.